# Getting Exception in Python code __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, exception, typeerror, flask-sqlalchemy

Arrows below show point where code throws an exception:

```
      def post(self, tagname):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('active', type=int, required=False, help="active required")
        parser.add_argument('desc', type=str, required=True, help="desc required")
        parser.add_argument('product', type=str, required=False, help="product optional")
        data = parser.parse_args()

       if t is None: #Tag exists - cannot create new Tag
         print(f"User does not exist - creating a  new Tag")
 >>>>>>  t = Tag(data).insert()
         return t.json(), 201
```

This is the constructor of the class:

```
    class Tag(sql_al_db.Model):
     
     __tablename__ = 'tags'
     id = sql_al_db.Column(sql_al_db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     tagname = sql_al_db.Column(sql_al_db.String(80))
     active = sql_al_db.Column(sql_al_db.Integer)
     desc = sql_al_db.Column(sql_al_db.String(120))
     product = sql_al_db.Column(sql_al_db.String(120))


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
     super(Tag, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     for key in ('tagname', 'active', 'desc', 'product'):
        if key in kwargs:
            setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])
     print("Set kwargs like so after initiating object")
     pprint(kwargs)
```

Exception Stack trace:

```
        line 72, in post
        t = Tag(data).insert()
        TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

---

I don't see what Im doing wrong here.

Comment: `__init__` expects `self` and `**kwargs`; you are passing `self` and `data`.  Passing `**data` _might_ work, otherwise you need to build the kwargs dictionary manually.

Comment: Thanks- that worked. But isnt data a Key-Value argument being passed. Im surprised that it needs 2 splats

Comment: Python distinguishes between passing a dict as a single coherent object (`data`) and passing it as exploded kwargs (`**data`).